# Is it possible to delete received or sent transaction in your mobile btc wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-wallet-app

Please help me to delete transactions from my wallet. I looked everywhere and cant find any help

Comment: What wallet app are you using?  What do you mean by "delete"?  Do you want to actually undo the transactions (normally not possible) or just not have them show up in your app?

Comment: I use bitcoin wallet 5.17 on my mobile. I just want to delet some transactions. Not undo i just don't want to see them anymore. Is that possible cause i don't see any option in settings

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because i have so many and i wanted to "clean" my wallet  thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin Wallet App doesn't have the option to delete or hide transactions from the list.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this answer to make it a little better.  For instance, you aren't even mentioning which wallet doesn't support these features.  Someone would have to look to the comments of the question in order to determine what you are referring to, and even then it's not clear.

Comment: @Jestin: I agree that the answer is pretty short, but to be fair, the tag "bitcoin-wallet-app" is referring to a specific wallet software of which Andreas is the maintainer. ;)

Comment: Actually does anyone of you know of any wallet that supports deleting/hiding transactions? Or, for that matter, any bank account? If not, I think we can make this a generic question, agnostic of any specific wallet.